# How to enable hdfs and mapred audit logs?

Tags: hadoop, logging, log4j, kerberos

I am hadoop-2.6.0 user in windows. I want to enable hdfs and mapred logs. I could enable hdfs audit log by setting the following property in **hadoop-env.cmd** but cannot enabled audit log for mapred.

```
set HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER=INFO,RFAAUDIT
```

If i set the above variable in hadoop-env.cmd then hdfs-audit.log file stored in the %HADOOP_LOG_DIR%.

I want to enable mapred audit logging. In log4j.properties available in the %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop, i could see the logging properties for mapred which is pasted below

**mapred audit logging**

```
mapred.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/mapred-audit.log
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex}
```

But cannot enable mapred audit logging. When i change the following properties then an empty file **mapred-audit.log** stored in the %HADOOP_LOG_DIR%.

```
mapred.audit.logger=INFO,MRAUDIT
-
-
-
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=true
-
-
```

How can i enable mapred audit logs?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://blog.csdn.net/u011281987/article/details/30034143)

As i am using YARN framework, i just added the below line in log4j.properties file for mapred.audit.logger

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
```